# x-www-form-urlencoded format - using https in node.js

Tags: node.js, api

I am currently writing to an API to try and get a token. I'm nearly there but fallen at the last hurdle..

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const ConfigParams = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Config.json', 'utf8'));
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const apikey = ConfigParams.client_id;


var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(**MY KEY**);
var tkn;

const jwtOptions = {
    algorithm: 'RS512',
    header: { kid: 'test-1' }
}


const jwtPayload = {
    iss: apikey,
    sub: apikey,
    aud: **API TOKEN ENDPOINT**,
    jti: '1',
    exp: 300
}

jwt.sign(jwtPayload,
    privateKey,
    jwtOptions,
    (err, token) => {
        console.log(err);
        //console.log(token);
        tkn = token;

        let = tokenPayload = {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            client_assertion_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer/',
            client_assertion: tkn
        }

        tokenAuthOptions = {
            payload: tokenPayload,
            host: **HOST**,
            path: **PATH**,
            method: 'POST',
            

        }
          
        https.request(
            tokenAuthOptions,
            resp => {
                var body = '';
                resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    body += chunk;
                });
                resp.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(body);
                    console.log(resp.statusCode);
                });
            }
        ).end(); 
    }
)
```

the encoded token comes back fine for the first part, the https request though returns a problem.

the response I get back is grant_type is missing, so I know I have a formatting problem due to this x-www-form-urlencoded, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

here is what the website said:

> You need to include the following data in the request body in
> x-www-form-urlencoded format:
>
> grant_type = client_credentials client_assertion_type =
> urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
> client_assertion = <your signed JWT from step 4> Here's a complete
> example, as a CURL command:
>
> curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> --data \ "grant_type=client_credentials\ &client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
> &client_assertion=" 
> **END POINT**

Ideally I want a solution using the https request, but if that's not possible I'm open to other solutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Craig

Edit - I updated my code based on a suggestion to:

```
const params = new url.URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_assertion_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer/',
    client_assertion: tkn
});

axios.post("URL", params.toString()).then(resp => {
    console.log("response was : " + resp.status);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("there was an error: " + err);
})
```

But I'm still getting an error code 400, but now with less detail as to why. (error code 400 has multiple message failures)

Comment: I don't see option `payload` here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback. And it's better to use something like `got` or `axios` to send such requests. Also, keep in mind that for `x-www-form-urlencoded` the body it shouldn't be JSON, it should be a special string.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try Axios rather than https. If anyone has previously done something like this before and can assist with the formatting that would be great.

Comment: Maybe it would be enough to prepare a string just like for axios, see here https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: I've just been on the same website :) I changed to axios and changed to in the main post. Unfortunately I'm now getting error 400 in the catch and it's giving me even less information on the response code error :(

Comment: Because you're doing all this in Node.js and not in a browser you need to use `qs`: https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman is the best.

Thank for @Anatoly for your support which helped to point me in the right direction. I had no luck so used postman for the first time, and found it had a code snippet section, with four different ways of achieving this using node.js.

The solution with Axion was:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const qs = require('qs');

        var data = qs.stringify({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_assertion_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
            'client_assertion': tkn
        });
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: '',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: data
        };

        axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.status));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I believe the issue was that I was not passing the information into 'data:' in combination with the querystring problem. Using qs.stringify to format the object, then passing this into the data: key solved the problem.